# pyparsing - load ABNF?

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

can pyparsing read ABNF from a file instead of having to define it in terms of python objects?

If not, is there something which can do similar (load an ABNF file into a parser object)

Answer (score 9):

See [this example](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/master/examples/ebnf.py) submitted by Seo Sanghyeon, which reads EBNF and parses it (using pyparsing) to create a pyparsing parser.

Comment: For a newcomer it isn't obvious how to use Seo's script.  Are there any examples of usage?

Comment: The link no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of Python parsing packages: [Python Parsing Tools](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/python-parsers.html).  [ANTLR](http://antlr.org) in particular is very well-respected, and reads a grammar from a dedicated file.